# Kohana 3, Detect dynamic uri

Tags: php, routes, kohana, kohana-3

I am making a mini webshop system, for practise, so you are able to create multiple webshops dynamically.

I currently have this:

```
Route::set('dynamic_routes', function($uri)
{
    $webshop = DB::select()->from('webshops')
        ->where('uri', '=', $uri)
        ->execute()
        ->get('id', 0);

    // Check if there is a match
    if ($webshop > 0)
    {
        define('WEBSHOP_ID', $webshop);

        return array(
            'controller' => 'shop',
            'action' => 'index',
            'directory' => 'shop'
        );
    }
}
);
```

This will handle so I can have dynamic routes by looking for the URI in the database.

If theres a webshop matching, it takes you to the index of the webshop. - Works fine.

Now this only works when you land on the root uri for the webshop eg "/myWebshop".

For all webshops I have two controllers, one called "shop" and other called "customer" and I would like them to be accessed by /myWebshop/shop/action and /myWebshop/customer/action

The issue for me here is that "myWebshop" is dynamic, and so is the action function method in either "shop" controller or "customer" controller.

How can i write two routes, that are dynamically?

This is how far I came:

```
if(strpos($uri, '/'))
{
    // If we have a /, and [1] isn't empty, we know that the user looks for subpage?
    $expl = explode('/', $uri);

    if(!empty($uri[1]))
    {
        // Set the uri to the first part, in order to find the webshop?
        $uri = $uri[0];
    }


$webshop = DB::select()->from('webshops')
    ->where('uri', '=', $uri)
    ->execute()
    ->get('id', 0);

// Check if there is a match
if ($webshop > 0)
{
    define('WEBSHOP_ID', $webshop);

    return array(
        'controller' => 'shop',
        'action' => 'index',
        'directory' => 'shop'
    );
}
}
```

I dont know what to do after this, how can I know create the dynamically routes and start pointing the user directly?

Answer (score 0):

Take out the controller and action part from URL the same way you did for `$uri`:

```
return array(
        'controller' => !empty($uri[1]) ? $uri[1] : 'some_default_controller',
        'action' => !empty($uri[2]) ? $uri[2] : 'some_default_action',
        'directory' => 'shop' // OR $uri[x] if it's also supposed to be dynamic
    );
```